# Rails 3 - get  and sort objects of model from related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 2 models, **Teacher** and **TeacherLeader**:

```
#  id        :integer
#  last_name :string(255)
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :teacher_leader
end

#  teacher_id :integer
class TeacherLeader < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

I want to get ALL teachers who are teachers leaders and sort them via `last_name`. How can i do that?

Comment: If I understand right, a teacher can be a "normal" teacher or, optionally, a teacher leader, right? If so, why don't you just put a boolean flag inside the teacher model?

Comment: @23tux No. If **TeacherLeader** model has `teacher_id` then we have another user. Thats why adding boolean flag isn't so good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Teacher.joins(:teacher_leader).uniq.order(:last_name)
```